# How can I use the latest react version (react18)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, frontend

When using npx create-react-app my-app, I got this error:

> You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).
> We no longer support global installation of Create React App.
> Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
> - npm uninstall -g create-react-app
> - yarn global remove create-react-app

I used the command npm uninstall and also check out the [getting started with react](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

but that links suggest the same process
of npx create-react-app my-app. I also used this command `npm install react react-dom` but this
only install a node modules and a package.json. It doesn't create the usual react boilerplate
and all. Anyone have any idea, please help.

Comment: I ran into this. Try `npx create-react-app@latest myApp`.

Comment: what version of node and npm are you using?

Comment: @TungPham node = v15.10.0 npm = 7.5.3

Comment: Looks like you instal `create-react-app` in global scope. Remove it ( console output suggests 2 variants) and call npx again

Comment: @Andy , from now on, do I have to use a command to install the latest react everytime or can I just use npx create-react-app@latest my-app ???

Comment: I'd just do the second thing. I don't have CRA installed globally and that's the only thing that works. @Rabten. I'm too lazy to figure out another solution :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
npx create-react-app@latest myApp
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to uninstall the glocal app and then clear the cache and then reinstall it.

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app

npx clear-npx-cache
```

After doing this reinstall it by running following command

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

If it still don't work make sure to update your npm and node version.

---

If you want to update the react and react-dom of the existing app to the latest version you can do it by following running the following code.

```
npm install --save react@latest
npm install --save react-dom@latest
```

If you want to download a specific version of react and react-dom then you can run the following code in your terminal.

```
npm install --save react@<version>
npm install --save react-dom@<version>
```

You need to replace  with your desired version for example

```
npm install --save react@17
```